# Issues with Stripe Connect

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Hope you are doing great days.

I am trying to set up payment by using stripe connect. I followed the tutorial 'https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts' and finished everything. (Admin account is Europe based)

But when I test my onboarding process, I can't create a European account(step 2 of above documentation). I am supposed to be a US based user and I am required to input US phone number, social digits and etc.

Of course I can pass this process with test methods(phone num: 000 000 0000). But when I pass with test data, I am registered as a United States based account in admin's connect account. Thus I can't transfer money from admin to registered account with 'stripe transfer api'. Error is occurred because admin and connected account are not from same region.

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem?

I tried to explain what my problem is but not sure I did it exactly. I will be happy if you contact me. Please feel free to ask me if you can't get what my problem is.

Many thanks.

Comment: `Express accounts can only be created for U.S. individuals and businesses` as it says on your link. Express accounts can't be created outside of the US right now, so that's why it requires US details.

Comment: Hi Karllekko. Thank you for your quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that stripe express account is only available in U.S.(Mr.Karllekko hinted me). I contacted with stripe support team and they say that Express account is not available in Germany. So I decided to implement current business logic with Custom account.

Thank you guys who are interested in my question. And thanks again, Karllekko.